# How to detect log4J on windows server 2016 Datacenter machine

Tags: java, windows-server-2016, log4j

So I recently got a mail about updating to the latest security update to the Apache software installed on my server *(vulnerability (CVE-2021-44228 & CVE-2021-45046) related to Apache Log4j)*, but how can I detect where this log4j is used?

When I run cmd: `java --version` I get:

[image]

Then I found a github log4j script checker: `./wget.exe https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rubo77/log4j_checker_beta/main/lo                                           g4j_checker_beta.sh -q -O - |bash` , but it didn't tell me that much

[image]

Is there another command I could run, to check where this log4j need to be updated on my server?

I do run XAMPP on this machine, but are log4j used here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to scan for log4j on Windows Server](https://serverfault.com/questions/1087504/how-to-scan-for-log4j-on-windows-server)

Comment: Maybe you don't have the vulnerability on this server? You could try a simple file search for any file name containing 'log4j' or *.jar. But this will not be definitive.

Comment: I tried Geralds link, and found this file: `Files/Amazon_Corretto/jdk11.0.11_9/lib/jrt-fs.jar
` How can i see if this uses log4j?